# Are Parameterized queries SQL standards?

Tags: sql

Are Parameterized queries SQL standards or are they just implementation of programming language in use?
I mean, in SQL document standards is it established that to create parameterized queries it is needed a question mark '?'?

Comment: I would imagine so.  Database engines can more effectively optimize execution paths if they receive the same query string with different parameters attached to it as opposed to different query strings.  Every ORM I've seen translates requests into queries with inline-attached parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, SQL prepare with `?` for parameter placeholders is standard SQL.

Here's a plain english description from "SQL-99 Complete, Really": https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sqlprepare/

The SQL-2003 SQL/Foundation standard, section 4.24.1, "Overview of dynamic SQL" says:

> Many SQL-statements can be written to use “parameters” (which are manifested in static execution of SQLstatements
>   as host parameters in s contained in s
>   in s or as host variables in s contained in
>   s). In SQL-statements that are executed dynamically, the parameters are called
>   dynamic parameters (s) and are represented in SQL language by a  (?).